# Push scripts to heroku without adding them to git repo

Tags: git, heroku

I have a public git repo that I use to push to my heroku app with 'git push heroku master'. But, a couple files that are needed to run the application are not included in the public repo for security reasons. How can I add files to heroku without having to use the 'git push' integration? I'd really like to be able to just add files to the server. Note, I have seen that heroku config variables solve questions similar to this one, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not write a general script that pulls in environment variables instead of hardcoding secret data?

Comment: If I had to I could do that, but this script would require a lot of env variables. It would be much easier to just hide the script from git but include it on the server.

Comment: @ritmatter, that's not how Heroku works. The environment variable suggestion is the correct answer here.

Comment: Ok, that's also a viable option. I ended up converting the javascript variables to environment variables and including a modified version of the script in my repo. Thanks for the advice.